When kafka node goes down from cluster facing issue with kafka streams connected this kafka cluster
I am using 3 nodes kafka cluster, And there are multiple kafka streams and producer's are connected.
I am facing issue when one of the node is going down from this kafka cluster.
Issue i am facing is like multiple kafka streams are in connected state but they are not consuimg messages when one of the kafka node's goes down. All messages are in kafka topic queue even streams are in connected state.
Details :-

Each topic is configured with replication_factor as 3.
Each topic is having 6 or more than 6 partitions.
All 3 kafka nodes are configured as Broker and Controller.
Number of kafka stream thread's are 3 and more.
Kafka cluster is deployed in kubernetes envi.
In bootstrap server mentioned all kafka node's address as well.

I have added below properties in kafka stream and done testing by deleteing kafka node pods.
Properties :-

(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000).
(StreamsConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 3000).
(StreamsConfig.TASK_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 300000).

But still facing same issue, That kafka streams are connected but not consuimg messages and message's are stored in kafka topic queue.
To start consuimg messages it is required to restart the kafka stream.
Can some one help what changes can be made, So that kafka stream's keep consuming messages even one of the kafka node goes down.

I suggest to check these two things, as they could be the root cause of no Stream processing when pods are added/removed (not necessarily Kafka nodes) or when Kafka tries to rebalance topic partitions to pods:
Check in your application/service that your stream doesn't stop processing when Kafka enters Rebalancing, as not every state change should cause the stream to stop and exit. For example, if you use a latch mechanism, check your condition on the latch, and fortify it "against" Rebalancing state like this:
kafkaStreams.setStateListener((state, previousState) -> { 
  // example; more conditions may be required here 
  if (KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING == previousState && state != KafkaStreams.State.REBALANCING) { 
                latch.countDown(); // allows the Stream thread to close and exit.  
            }
});

Check also the consumer group IDs for each topic you use: Verify that each topic has its own consumer group ID, as using the same group ID for multiple topics may result in a rebalancing loop.
